# How to invalidate L1 data cache for a specific memory range on PowerPC PQ-III e500?

Tags: powerpc, cpu-cache

A special memory block would be periodically updated by DMA task. When another Task tried to look up data in this block frequently, there is MCE (Machine Check Exception) about L1 data cache parity check. 
Can I invalidate the L1 Data Cache for this memory block totally or only after DMA update?

There is an interesting API in libogc like:

```
void DCInvalidateRange(void *startaddress,u32 len); 

    .globl DCInvalidateRange
DCInvalidateRange:
    cmplwi r4, 0   # zero or negative size?
    blelr
    clrlwi. r5, r3, 27  # check for lower bits set in address
    beq 1f
    addi r4, r4, 0x20 
1:
    addi r4, r4, 0x1f
    srwi r4, r4, 5
    mtctr r4
2:
    dcbi r0, r3
    addi r3, r3, 0x20
    bdnz 2b
    blr
```

I am not familiar with ASM neither ASM on PowerPC. Would people recommend links or descriptions on this operation?

Comment: http://www.freescale.com/files/32bit/doc/app_note/AN3544.pdf provided a means to operate on the TLB flags but it is not a direct operation on user space addresses for MPC8540 e500.

Comment: I have tried to disable the L1 Data Cache with below instructions in ko init phase, but it failed with sys-trap.

    __asm__ volatile ("eieio;sync");
    mtspr(SPRN_L1CSR0, 0x00000000);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the best resource, the [PowerPC Programming Environments Manual](http://www.freescale.com/files/product/doc/MPCFPE32B.pdf)

Are there specific questions you have about the cache?

Working with DMA, your choices are snooping or cache flushing.  To get this error, you probably have snooping enabled.  So the problem is likely that you have data in L1 cache that is uninitialized.

There's a second resource, the [E500 Core Reference Manual](http://cache.freescale.com/files/32bit/doc/ref_manual/E500CORERM.pdf), which I couldn't download at the moment but which should give a good description of how to init the cache.  I use the E-600 book all the time.

Comment: David, I have tried 1st step to disable L1 Data Cache when loading a private ko. But the board reboots when below instruction in the initialize function being performed. The error logs show that several "Slab corruption" occurred and then after the initialize_func performed and the ko loaded in kernel, the kernel has a kernel stack overflow reported before reboot.  The logs I ahve mentioned: (1) 38E12D103: 14/03/1902 UTC 06:31:32, [  366.427292] Slab corruption: size-32 start=8b4de9e0, len=32 (2) 38E420545: 14/03/1902 UTC 06:31:32, [  366.497530]  80<2>Kernel stack overflow in process.

Comment: @iMax - you have to be careful disabling the cache.  if you don't flush the data first, you will lose data the kernel has written.  That might cause the stack overflow.  Any chance you could disable snooping on the DMA as a test?

Comment: Thanks for your reminder. I have not flushed the L1 data before disabling L1 data cache. This way I would read the 2nd source you have mentioned above and find the method to test two cases: 1) Flush the L1 data cache before disabling L1 Data Cache (this is a private test to determine whether L1 Data cache parity check was caused by misusing DMA; 2) Trying to enable L1 data cache snooping with DMA. Since I am not familiar with ASM instructions, it would cost some time. I would like to let you know the result. Anyway you have pointed out the way to resolve my problem.